# CSS3 animation doesn't take all the images

Tags: css, animation

I'm new with CSS3 animation and I'm trying to create a simple animation with image sequence using 164 images in the DOM and CSS keyframes to show each one in order.

Everything is working very good but the animation is not running completely, it just show the first 60 images with a duration of 2 seconds.

In fact, if I increase the height in my animation object I can see the other images running the animation in the down side, like if it splits the animation in 3 parts of 60 images each one.

Here is the code that I'm using.

Is it possible that maybe HTML5 only can use 60 images and only show 2 seconds?

I would appreciate some help with this.

index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Animation test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="animation-object">
    <div class="animation-object__strip">
      <img src="images/image1.png"> 
      <!-- Bunch of images of sequence here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```
html{
  background: #ffd25c;
}

.animation-object {
  width: 640px;
  height: 960px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.animation-object__strip:nth-of-type(1){
  width: 34040px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  animation-timing-function: step-start;
  -webkit-animation: intro 2s steps(30) infinite;
  animation: intro 2s steps(30) infinite; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes intro {
  from { -webkit-transform:  translateX(0px); }
  to { -webkit-transform:  translateX(-19200px); }
}
```

Comment: Let's be clear. What you are asking about is CSS3 animation and nothing about HTML5. And, no, HTML5 is not limited to the number of images or time.

Comment: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/#cfimg3